# FileWriter method doesn't print anything unless append is true

Tags: java, file, append

Newbie here. My goal is to read a txt file, eliminate characters ("-" and " "), and replace the existing text with the new cleaned up text.

example: 855-555-1234 >> 8555551234.

I'm stuck on my append boolean. I'm using the guides [here](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/read_a_textfile_in_java.html) and [here](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/write_to_textfile.html).

When my append is true then I get the text that I want at the end of the file, but when it is false, the file is completely blank.

My main method looks like:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String file_name = "C:/TollFreeToPort.txt";
    try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        WriteFile data = new WriteFile(file_name, true);

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            data.writeToFile(aryLines[i]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

My ReadFile Class:

```
package textfiles;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ReadFile {

private String path;

public ReadFile(String file_path) {
    path = file_path;
}

public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

    int numberOfLines = readLines();
    String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        textData[i] = textReader.readLine()
        .replace("-", "")
        .replace(" ", "");
    }

    textReader.close();

    return textData;

}

int readLines() throws IOException {
    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

    String aLine;
    int numberOfLines = 0;

    while ((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        numberOfLines++;
    }
    bf.close();

    return numberOfLines;
  }
}
```

My WriteFile Class:

```
package textfiles;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteFile {

private  String path;
private boolean append_to_file = false;

public WriteFile(String file_path) {
    path = file_path;
}

public WriteFile(String file_path, boolean append_value) {
    path = file_path;
    append_to_file = append_value;
}

public void writeToFile (String textLine) throws IOException{
    FileWriter write = new FileWriter(path, append_to_file);
    PrintWriter print_line = new PrintWriter(write);

    print_line.printf("%s" + "%n", textLine);
    print_line.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: My my, many many things wrong with your code. So, first question: is this pure educational (you are learning things), or supposed to do real world work?

Comment: Things to look at anyway: A) java naming conventions ... you are violating them all over the place B) naming in general: like: `OpenFile()` ... a now: that reads a file into an array, it does much more than just open a file. Names should mean what they say! For example it is **also** changing your input strings. Dont do that. Have one method to read all lines, then one to **update** then, and then write the updated stuff out.

Comment: And if this is supposed to be a real world solution, well. Start by throwing it all away, to then use `Files.readAllLines()`, and streams, and so on.

Comment: Also consider to use the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). It "_ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement._".

Comment: Haha. Yes I'm a definite noob and am using this as a learning opportunity. This would be useful for my day job though.  as for naming conventions, other than my OpenFile() that I frankesteined, what else did I screw up? I mostly used the names from the guide that I linked at the top.

Comment: I took a look at the linked examples. I wouldn't recommend them. They are using pictures of code instead the code itself. The shown code contains unused imports, the written text has typos. Seems to me to have low quality even at the first glance.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I will try to go through all of this again with your suggestions. Obviously I have a long way to go but in the short term, is there any explanation for my original question? Why will it only print if it is appending?  Thanks again.